# windows macro RT_WIN32

Tags: windows, visual-studio, winapi, operating-system, kernel

In my windows project, i found two macros

```
#ifndef WIN32
#define WIN32

#define RT_WIN32
```

I found information about `WIN32` but what is `RT_WIN32`? Is this work for x64 bit system. I am using windows 7 and ndis 5.x miniport and 2010 visual studio and winddk 7

Comment: It doesn't mean anything.  Search the rest of the codebase to see what side-effects it has.

Comment: "RT" typically indicates something related to the modern/metro/win8 set of APIs for developing touch apps on Windows 8.  I just grepped for RT_WIN32 in my VS2013 SDK install. It didn't find anything.